# custom module, with custom table(custom data) with integration Data Mining (WEKA)

Tags: 7

I have developed a module that retrieves some data from the web (tweets) in JSON format.
These data are analyzed by the software for Data Mining [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and finally a model is created that must be applied to future data so that we can get the best information ...
Now .. WEKA is a Java-based software while Drupal is based on PHP.
Maybe my question is stupid ... but how do I integrate and launch the analysis of WEKA from my Drupal module?
The module produces structured data in a CSV file on which to launch the analysis and stores the data in a custom table.
I ask for help to the experts? .. This job is for a university thesis.
Thank you.

Comment: Presumably you'd need to write a java applet if you want to run a java app in the browser. Either way the question isn't really about Drupal - if you can tell us how you would launch a java app from a non-Drupal php application, we can certainly help you to integrate that logic into a Drupal module if you're struggling. But please remember this site is strictly for questions about Drupal, we can't help you with issues relating to java as such

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question is how can start an application java from Drupal module and passing a file CSV like parameter, all in general. I want understana. 
I would like to understand the logic with which I can integrate it into drupal I see on web and in general forum that php and Java can comunicate through XML-RPC. Sorry for my language.